# Accessing the eBay Developer's API through Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ebay-api

I've been searching for a library to use to access the eBay Dev API (using *Python 3*) for quite some time, but the sources I've found either don't specify the use of Python 3 (and I've learned to assume that this means they use 2.x) or haven't been updated for years.

Can somebody point me in the right direction? Is there a library I'm missing? Or should I try to implement it myself? If I have to implement it myself...any words/tutorials to help? I'm really confused here....thanks in advance.

eBay API can be found in this general link: https://www.x.com/developers/ebay/documentation-tools/tutorials

And 2.7x isn't obsolete? Pray tell why it won't be in a couple years? Or...just...what?

*sigh* due to the words spoken here and read elsewhere...I'll just bite the bullet and re-learn Python in 2.7.x....whatever. Thanks anyways.

Comment: You're not going to be obsolete or out of date if you use Python 2.7.x and the support and libraries available are far better...

Comment: Consider updating one of the libraries to work with Python 3. [ebay-python-sdk](http://code.google.com/p/ebay-sdk-python/) looks fairly small and actively maintained, so that's a good bet.

Answer (score 12):

[python-ebay](https://github.com/roopeshvaddepally/python-ebay) is a python wrapper for eBay APIs. It [covers most of the eBay APIs](https://github.com/roopeshvaddepally/python-ebay/wiki/List-of-eBay-APIs).

PS: I wrote it.

Comment: You need the GetItem call: http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/GetItem.html, some sample code in java: http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/javasdk-jaxb/docs/libref/com/ebay/sdk/call/GetItemCall.html

Unfortunately, I have not implemented it yet in python-ebay. Would love if you could implement it here: https://github.com/roopeshvaddepally/python-ebay/blob/master/ebay/trading.py

Comment: could I use the getsingleitem?  that ones also seems to work, no?

Comment: I think the ebay shopping is good enough... I am trying to use the API to reproduce the following search: http://www.ebay.com/sch/PC-Laptops-Netbooks-/177/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=hp+laptop&_dmpt=Laptops_Nov05&Type=Notebook&rt=nc, and get the same number of results, then I'd try to get info about each single item, does that sound doable? a good stratregy?

Comment: Well sure, but you won't get *all* the info about an item. But depends on how much you actually need.

Comment: It seems to be ok but I am still struggling on how to reproduce a given search, like this one: `http://www.ebay.com/sch/PC-Laptops-Netbooks-/177/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=hp+laptop&_dmpt=Laptops_Nov05&Type=Notebook&rt=nc`. If I use FindProducts I do not get all the hp laptops, and I am not sure how to reproduce the exact same results as in the search, do you have any suggestion about it?

Comment: I think, you need to use http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsByKeywords.html to simulate the exact search as on the ebay search page.

Comment: This does not seem to support Python 3 :(

Answer (score 3):

I tried [python-ebay](https://github.com/roopeshvaddepally/python-ebay) but it doesn't implement every function of the Finding API (for example, there is no `findCompletedItems` function).

The alternative [ebaysdk-python](https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python) seems to be more actively maintained, is a little more flexible and does everything I need in a more simple way (IMO).

For example, getting completed items for a category is as simple as:

```
api = finding(appid='APP_ID')
api.execute('findCompletedItems', {'categoryId': '619'})
print api.response_dict()
```

The dictionary that's passed to the execute function exactly mirrors the [eBay Finding API documentation](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findCompletedItems.html#detailControls), so if you can read that, you can basically do anything you need with the above three line of code.

Comment: FWIW, ebaysdk-python is listed on https://go.developer.ebay.com/ebay-sdks

Answer (score 3):

The official eBay page https://go.developer.ebay.com/ebay-sdks recommends https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python . Currently ebaysdk-python has been updated 9 days ago and regularly since 2011, while python-ebay hasn't been updated for 20 months.